# Mission planning vs path planning vs motion planning

Tags: motion-planning, path-planning

I am struggling to understand the difference between mission planning, path planning, and motion planning. This answer on [stack exchange](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/8302/what-is-the-difference-between-path-planning-and-motion-planning) clarified the difference between path planning and motion planning. However, where does mission planning come in?

From what I understand mission planning includes motion planning and path planning.

Answer (score 1):

These are 3 different layers of abstraction.

Mission planning on top
then Path planning, then
Motion planning

Mission planning is: how are we going to get the robot from A to B while achieving sub goals C, D, and E?
Very high level description of overall goals to complete.

Path planning is: These are the waypoints that we will visit that aren't too costly (inside a building or a wall or other obstruction).

Motion planning is: What motor velocity curves do we need to go from waypoint 2 to waypoint 3 considering the constraints of the drivetrain?

Does this make sense?